# Preserve color of a state in mouseover function in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map created from a geojson using d3.js lib and I colored randomly different states of map. Now I want to get color of a state when I hover it in mouseover function :

```
var lastColor;

function mouseover(d) {
     lastColor = d.color; //This code is not works for me

     d3.select(this)
         .style('fill', 'orange')
         .style('cursor', 'pointer');
}

function mouseout(d) {
    d3.select(this)
         .style('fill', lastColor);
}
```

Is it possible to get the color from d so that I return to this color when I mouseout from this state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `on` function, `this` refers to the DOM element. So, if you set the colour using `style`, you can get the same colour using `style` as a getter:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    console.log(d3.select(this).style("fill"))//'style' as a getter
});
```

Check this demo, hovering over the states (I set the colours using `Math.random()`):

```js
var width = 720,
    height = 375;

var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(800)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/232969/cnn/us.json", function(error, us) {


    svg.selectAll(".state")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style('fill', function(d) {
            return colorScale(Math.random() * 20)
        })
        .attr('class', 'state')
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            console.log(d3.select(this).style("fill"))
        });

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
            return a !== b;
        }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "state-boundary");

});
```

```css
.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.county-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

.state-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: I have to confess that I read only the title of your question when you first posted it ("How to find the color of a state in mouseover"). Now, after properly reading the text of your post, I reckon the solution is even easier (btw, "Preserve the color of a state" is indeed a better title to the question).

If you set the colour using any property in the data (let's say, `id`):

```
.style('fill', function(d){
    return colorScale(d.id)
})
```

You can simply set it again in the "mouseout":

```
.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "orange")
}).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style('fill', function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.id)
    })
});
```

Check this other demo:

```js
var width = 720,
    height = 375;
    
var colorScale = d3.scale.category20();

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(800)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/232969/cnn/us.json", function(error, us) {
      
    
    svg.selectAll(".state")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style('fill', function(d){
            return colorScale(d.id)
        })        
        .attr('class', 'state')
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
         d3.select(this).style("fill", "orange")
        }).on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this).style('fill', function(d){
            return colorScale(d.id)
        })});
    
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
            return a !== b;
        }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "state-boundary");
 
});
```

```css
.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.county-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

.state-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Obtice I just added another demo that I think will suit you better.